# Django: Unable to login on site but on local server it works, not on site

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have tried to check my code, but I can't find the solution or bug...
On local server the site runs normally, login works.

but I have installed it on A2 hosting server, and the site runs but I can't login, I have logged in with correct user and password. But it always returned to wrong page and I'm not logged in, the session id cookie is set... Can someone help me?
here the code of my settings

## Django settings for signbank project.

```
import os
from signbank.settings.server_specific import *
from datetime import datetime

DEBUG = True

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'

LOCALE_PATHS = [BASE_DIR+'conf/locale']

SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = WRITABLE_FOLDER
MEDIA_URL = URL+'/media/'
MEDIA_MOBILE_URL = MEDIA_URL

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/signbank/SB/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = URL+'/files/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "static"),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '^g=q21r_nnmbz49d!vs*2gvpll-y9b@&amp;t3k2r3c$*u&amp;2la5!%s_'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'signbank.pages.middleware.PageFallbackMiddleware',
#    'django_mobile.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
#    'django_mobile.middleware.SetFlavourMiddleware',
#    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates/' + SIGNBANK_VERSION_CODE + '-templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "signbank.context_processors.url",
                "signbank.pages.context_processors.menu",
#                "django_mobile.context_processors.flavour",
            ],
            'loaders': [
#                'django_mobile.loader.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]
        },
    },
]

# add the Email backend to allow logins using email as username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "signbank.registration.EmailBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'dictionary.UserProfile'

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'signbank.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'signbank.wsgi.application'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_summernote',
    'signbank.dictionary',
    'signbank.feedback',
    #'signbank.registration',
    'signbank.pages',
    'signbank.attachments',
    'signbank.video',
    'reversion',
    #'django_mobile',
    'tagging',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


# turn on lots of logging or not
DO_LOGGING = True
LOG_FILENAME = "debug.log"


SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False


## Application settings for signbank


## Settings controlling page contents

# what do we call this signbank?
LANGUAGE_NAME = "VGT"
COUNTRY_NAME = "België"

# do we implement safe search for anonymous users?
# if True, any gloss that is tagged lexis:crude will be removed from
# search results for users who are not logged in
ANON_SAFE_SEARCH = False

# do we show the tag based search for anonymous users?
ANON_TAG_SEARCH = False


# do we display the previous/next links to signs, requires gloss.sn to be used consistently
SIGN_NAVIGATION = False

# which definition fields do we show and in what order?
DEFINITION_FIELDS = ['general', 'noun', 'verb', 'interact', 'deictic', 'modifier', 'question', 'augment', 'note']

ADMIN_RESULT_FIELDS = ['annotation_idgloss', 'annotation_idgloss_en', 'handedness', 'domhndsh', 'subhndsh', 'locprim']


# location and URL for uploaded files
UPLOAD_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + "upload/"
UPLOAD_URL = MEDIA_URL + "upload/"

# Location for comment videos relative to MEDIA_ROOT
COMMENT_VIDEO_LOCATION = "comments"
# Location for videos associated with pages
PAGES_VIDEO_LOCATION = 'pages'
# location for upload of videos relative to MEDIA_ROOT
# videos are stored here prior to copying over to the main
# storage location
VIDEO_UPLOAD_LOCATION = "upload"

# path to store uploaded attachments relative to MEDIA_ROOT
ATTACHMENT_LOCATION = 'attachments'

# which fields from the Gloss model should be included in the quick update form on the sign view
QUICK_UPDATE_GLOSS_FIELDS = ['signlanguage', 'dialect', 'tag_cat']

# should we always require a login for viewing dictionary content
ALWAYS_REQUIRE_LOGIN = True

# name of the primary css file, relative to the media directory
PRIMARY_CSS = "bootstrap_css/test-server.css"


# do we allow people to register for the site
ALLOW_REGISTRATION = False

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7



# show the number signs page or an under construction page?
SHOW_NUMBERSIGNS = True

LOGIN_URL = URL+'/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = URL+'/signs/recently_added/'


# location of ffmpeg, used to convert uploaded videos
FFMPEG_PROGRAM = "/Applications/ffmpegX.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg"
FFMPEG_TIMEOUT = 60
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = ["-vcodec", "h264", "-an"]


# defines the aspect ratio for videos
VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO = 3.0/4.0

# settings for django-tagging
FORCE_LOWERCASE_TAGS = False

PRIMARY_CSS = "css/"+SIGNBANK_VERSION_CODE+"/main.css"

# defines the aspect ratio for videos
#VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO = 360.0/640.0


# what do we call this signbank?
LANGUAGE_NAME = "VGT"
COUNTRY_NAME = "België"

# show/don't show sign navigation
SIGN_NAVIGATION = False

# show the number signs page or an under construction page?
#SHOW_NUMBERSIGNS = False

# do we show the 'advanced search' form and implement 'safe' search?
#ADVANCED_SEARCH = False

# which definition fields do we show and in what order?
#DEFINITION_FIELDS = []


#ADMIN_RESULT_FIELDS = ['idgloss', 'annotation_idgloss']

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {},
    'loggers': {},
}


import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("video/mp4", ".mov", True)



# a list of tags we're allowed to use
XALLOWED_TAGS = [ '',
                 'workflow:needs video',
                 'workflow:redo video',
                 'workflow:problematic',
                 'corpus:attested',
                 'lexis:doubtlex',
                 'phonology:alternating',
                 'phonology:dominant hand only',
                 'phonology:double handed',
                 'phonology:forearm rotation',
                 'phonology:handshape change',
                 'phonology:onehand',
                 'phonology:parallel',
                 'phonology:symmetrical',
                 'phonology:two handed',
                ]

# allow iedereen -> '*' leeg= niemand of enkel localhost = default
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

EARLIEST_GLOSS_CREATION_DATE = datetime(2015,1,1)
SUPPORTED_CITATION_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.png']
MAXIMUM_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5000000

MINIMUM_OVERLAP_BETWEEN_SIGNING_HANDS_IN_CNGT = 40
```

import os

```
ROOT = '/home/signbank/SB/'
BASE_DIR=ROOT
WRITABLE_FOLDER = ROOT+'writable/'

DATABASES = {'default':
                {
                    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                    'NAME': ROOT+'signbank.db',
                }
            }

#Influences which template and css folder are used
SIGNBANK_VERSION_CODE = 'VGT'
URL = 'http://signbank.a2hosted.com'

LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', 'English'),
  ('nl', 'Dutch'),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

SEPARATE_ENGLISH_IDGLOSS_FIELD = True

FIELDS = {}

FIELDS['main'] = ['useInstr','wordClass']

FIELDS['phonology'] = ['handedness','domhndsh','subhndsh','handCh','relatArtic','locprim','locVirtObj',
          'relOriMov','relOriLoc','oriCh','contType','movSh','movDir','repeat','altern','phonOth', 'mouthG',
          'mouthing', 'phonetVar',]

FIELDS['semantics'] = ['iconImg','namEnt','semField','semField1','semField2','semField3','semField4']

FIELDS['frequency'] = ['tokNo','tokNoSgnr','tokNoA','tokNoSgnrA','tokNoWV','tokNoSgnrWV','tokNoOV','tokNoSgnrOV','tokNoL','tokNoSgnrL',
                       'tokNoVB','tokNoSgnrVB','tokNoO','tokNoSgnrO']

ECV_FILE = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'ecv/vgt.ecv'
ECV_SETTINGS = {
    'CV_ID': '',
    'include_phonology_and_frequencies': True,
    'languages': []
}

GLOSS_VIDEO_DIRECTORY = 'glossvideo'
GLOSS_IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'glossimage'
CROP_GLOSS_IMAGES = True
OTHER_MEDIA_DIRECTORY = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'othermedia/'
WSGI_FILE = ROOT+'signbank/wsgi.py'
VIDEOS_TO_IMPORT_FOLDER = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'import_videos/'
IMAGES_TO_IMPORT_FOLDER = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'import_images/'
OTHER_MEDIA_TO_IMPORT_FOLDER = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'import_other_media/'
SIGNBANK_PACKAGES_FOLDER = WRITABLE_FOLDER+'packages/'

CNGT_EAF_FILES_LOCATION = ''
CNGT_METADATA_LOCATION = ''

FFMPEG_PROGRAM = "avconv"
TMP_DIR = "/tmp"

API_FIELDS = [
    'idgloss',
    'annotation_idgloss',
    'annotation_idgloss_en',
]
```

**edit**
here is the code for login:

```
def mylogin(request, template_name='registration/login.html', redirect_field_name='/signs/recently_added/'):
    "Displays the login form and handles the login action."

    redirect_to = request.GET[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME] if REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME in request.GET else ''
    error_message = ''

    if request.method == "POST":
        if REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME in request.POST:
            redirect_to = request.POST[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME]

        form = EmailAuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            #Count the number of logins
            profile = form.get_user().user_profile_user
            profile.number_of_logins += 1
            profile.save()

            #Expiry date cannot be in the past
            if profile.expiry_date != None and date.today() > profile.expiry_date:
                form = EmailAuthenticationForm(request)
                error_message = _('This account has expired. Please contact thijs.vandamme@vgtc.be')

            else:
                # Light security check -- make sure redirect_to isn't garbage.
                if not redirect_to or '//' in redirect_to or ' ' in redirect_to:
                    redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())
                if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                    request.session.delete_test_cookie()

                # For logging in API clients
                if "api" in request.GET and request.GET['api'] == 'yes':
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': 'true'}), content_type='application/json')

                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            if "api" in request.GET and request.GET['api'] == 'yes':
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': 'false'}), content_type='application/json')
            error_message = _('The username or password is incorrect.')

    else:
        form = EmailAuthenticationForm(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    if Site._meta.installed:
        current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        current_site = RequestSite(request)

    # For logging in API clients
    if request.method == "GET" and "api" in request.GET and request.GET['api'] == 'yes':
        token = get_token(request)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token}), content_type='application/json')

    return render(request,template_name, {
        'form': form,
        REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME: settings.URL+redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
        'allow_registration': settings.ALLOW_REGISTRATION,
        'error_message': error_message})
mylogin = never_cache(mylogin)
```

I have checked or the session is stored in db ( django_session ) and its stored and I looked at the cookie, they have same key, so the problem is probably not cookie, but It keeps showing not logging in after "login" 
I can't find where i get wrong

Comment: please provide exception/error output

Comment: Did you create the user in your production db? How?

Comment: there is no exception/error output...

Comment: "But it always returned to wrong page " What do you mean by that?

Comment: if i try to login it always returned to this page: http://signbank.a2hosted.com/accounts/login/?next=http%3A//signbank.a2hosted.com/

Comment: one main difference is : Locally i did it from to command "runserver" and online is with wsgi thats only one difference

Comment: I didn't create user, but in my dev ( at runserver instead of wsgi file ) there are users and it works, I use the same db for online. So all the users are set there